# Overwriting a plugin function

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I need to write a function in my own plugin and overwrite a function from another plugin and (preferably) not make any changes to it. Or WordPress' core. So, basically, what I need to happen is: plugin X do it's work, it's time for function Y to do something, and instead of X's Y function, my function comes and do Y's job. Then X goes back to it's other functions.

I know the question has been asked before (some 3-4 years ago, when there were hooks) but any help'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the plugin itself provides hooks that you can use, or has been written is such a way as to be replaceable (a dicey proposition for a plugin), you can't. This isn't a WordPress restriction. It is a PHP one. You cannot "overload" or redefine functions in PHP. You will get a fatal error.